# ASP.NET Core Linq Compare Id and Sum value

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, sum, compare

I have a problem and unfortunately can not find the solution!
This is my database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pglN6.png)

and I would like to store all PaymentSum(double) [PaymentInformation] in the Total (double) [Document].

This is the SQL statement:

```
Select SUM(PaymentSum)
from PaymentInformations
where DocumentId = 1;
```

I have tried this, but without success:

```
// POST: api/PaymentInformations
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPost("new/{eId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<PaymentInformation>> PostpaymentInformations(long eId, PaymentInformation paymentInformation)
    {
        Document document = await _context.Documents.FindAsync(eId);


        document.Total = _context.PaymentInformations
                            .Where(b => b.Document.Id == eId)
                            .Sum(a => a.PaymentSum);


        //document.Total = _context.PaymentInformations.FromSqlRaw("Select SUM(PaymentSum) from PaymentInformations where DocumentId = {0}",eId).FirstOrDefault();
       
       

        foreach (var item in _context.PaymentInformations)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.PaymentSum);
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.DocumentId);
         
        }
       
        _context.PaymentInformations.Add(paymentInformation);

        document.addPaymentInformation(paymentInformation);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetpaymentInformations", new { id = paymentInformation.Id }, paymentInformation);
       
    }
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting document.Total correctly, are you perhaps overriding the Total value when you call document.addPaymentInformation(paymentInformation) further down?

Comment: I set an breakpoint in the calculation and it has shown that the id matches, but the sum is still not handed over.

Comment: Could you perhaps show what addPaymentInformation() does please? Also, I assume if you run this query in SQL, SUM(PaymentSum) brings back a Total > 0?

Comment: in SQL, SUM(PaymentSum) gives me exactly the right result.  I have added an image of the addPaymentinformation.

Comment: Ok I see, it looks like the ordering of your actions might be the issue. You need to insert your paymentInformation, then SaveChanges before you read your documents, then the last thing you do is sum the Total for Document and then lastly Save Changes. The way you have written this can be improved as it does not quite conform to SOLID principles. Much to learn still ;-)

Comment: Will change the order and look at the SOLID principles, and yes there is still a lot for me to learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

I set an breakpoint and it has shown that the id matches

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw2gm.png)

transfer without success

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxvKt.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addPaymentInformation(PaymentInformation paymentInformation)
    {
        if (PaymentInformations == null)
        {
            PaymentInformations = new List<PaymentInformation>();
        }
        paymentInformation.Document = this;
        PaymentInformations.Add(paymentInformation);

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).